# force ajax request on back and forward button with pjax

Tags: ajax, pjax

This call to pjax works and it replaces div-section with response from url.
For tabbed navigation, pjax successfully changes url as well

```
$.pjax({
        url: $this.attr("href"), 
        container: '#div-section', 
        push: true
}).done(function() {
        $object.init();                 
});
```

But back and forward chrome button don't resend Ajax request and its cached in browser. Also below setting is enabled to not force full refresh.

```
$.pjax.defaults.timeout = false;
```

how can ajax request be forced on back and forward button with pjax ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution for it

```
$.pjax.defaults.maxCacheLength = 0;
```